# nbconvert markdown not searching predefined images

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering why ipython nbconvert --to markdown not searching the image in directory first.

If i do this in my tes.ipynb:

```py
from Ipython.display import Image
Image('tes_files/1.jpg')
```

then if i execute command

```sh
ipython nbconvert tes.ipynb --to markdown --stdout
```

what i will get the output is

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('tes_files/1.jpg')
![jpeg](tes_files/tes_0_0.jpeg)
```

Why nbconvert not searching for the path specified by the path first,

then if it doesn't exist, generate a new one?

I know maybe there's some idea that we can import image from all directory and with nbconvert, markdown just gathering it into one folder.

Is there another option command? Do i have to create a new profile?

### UPDATE:

Suppose I have set the url path for the image folders:

> IMG_FOLDERS = '../galleries/tes_files'

and set the url path to that directory. At some point, I create a plot.
Then when I execute nbconvert, it just create a new folder 'name'_files, same dir as the ipynb, and create a new image based on the plot inside it. How to tell the nbconvert not to create a new directory, but instead, use IMG_FOLDERS?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your updated question... there is currently no possibility to change the output directory of nbconvert. the behavior is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/38e125443b51d2ab3252dbce62a8587c1ea9cb6b/IPython/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py#L295).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here, is that the IPython `Image` class embeds the image data into the notebook if you use it like you did in your example. Embedded images are extracted by a preprocessor from the notebook and finally included in the markdown, latex, etc. document during the conversion.
So what you are looking for is a way to link an image to the notebook, which is still possible with the `Image` class.
If you check the documentation for the `Image` class (IPython 2.3) you will find:

```
Init definition: Image(self, data=None, url=None, filename=None, format=u'png', embed=None, width=None, height=None, retina=False)

...

Parameters
----------
data : unicode, str or bytes
    The raw image data or a URL or filename to load the data from.
    This always results in embedded image data.
url : unicode
    A URL to download the data from. If you specify `url=`,
    the image data will not be embedded unless you also specify `embed=True`.
filename : unicode
    Path to a local file to load the data from.
    Images from a file are always embedded.
```

Hence, to get the image not embedded but rather linked, you have to use the `url` argument like:

```py
Image(url='tes_files/1.jpg')
```

There, is also an `embed` argument but this doesn't seem to work with the filename argument.